# C# - Disable Task manager error

Tags: c#, .net, registry, taskmanager

The code is as follows:

```
    public void KillCtrlAltDelete()  
    {
        RegistryKey regkey;
        string keyValueInt = "1";
        string subKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";

        try
        {
            regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(subKey);
            regkey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", keyValueInt);
            regkey.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But I was getting the following error.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException:Access to the registry key'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System' is denied.

at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)

at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistrySecurity registrySecurity)

at BlockTask.Form1.KillCtrlAltDelete() in C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BlockTask\BlockTask\Form1.cs:line 28
```

**How do you fix it?**

Comment: Run your program as administrator.

Comment: Use regedit, navigate to that key, right click on it and choose Permissions.... Set corresponding permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Run this Application on Administrator mode